# Differences between #lang scheme and #lang racket

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

I'm guessing that #lang racket is a dialect of scheme with much more out of the box structures and common functions and perhaps would be more pedagogic. What are the perks a #lang racket against #lang scheme?

Is it best (or even possible) to use #lang scheme in racket to follow all the content of 'Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs' or even 'How to Design Programs'. HtDP is #lang racket specific?

Whatever code written in #lang scheme, as long as libraries are not being included, can be used in chicken scheme or any main interpreter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Racket different from Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345397/how-is-racket-different-from-scheme)

Answer (score 36):

1. Yes, `#lang racket` is the racket default dialect, with lots of extensions.
2. Two places where it is not an extension: `if` must have an else branch, and pairs are immutable (no `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`).
3. `#lang scheme` was used for a while before the name change, and now `#lang racket` is used consistently.  But we kept `#lang scheme` around for compatibility (as well as various `scheme/---` libraries that are kept and can sometime be different than `racket/---` counterparts).  There's no reason to use `#lang scheme` in new code.
4. To follow SICP, don't use any of these -- there's a [SICP language](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html) available (usable with `#lang sicp`), originally written by Neil Van Dyke, but now maintained within the Racket community.
5. To follow HtDP, don't use any of these, use the student languages.  There are also new `#lang`-based variants like `#lang htdp/bsl` but they're not in a complete shape, yet.  (And HtDP is *not* `#lang racket` specific.)
6. No, Racket is *very* different from Chicken Scheme.  You might be able to run some code in both, but those would probably be only tiny toy examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info Eli, being for the pedagogic purpose I'll go totally with racket, what was very cool of chicken scheme is the compile to C part.

Comment: With Racket there's not much need to compile to C -- it uses a just-in-time compiler that performs pretty well.  If you're concerned about creating standalone executables rather than speed, then there are ways to do that too -- see `raco exe` and `raco distribute`.

Comment: Just to emphasize one thing here: `#lang scheme` is almost exactly the same as `#lang racket` -- it is not any more similar to Chicken Scheme, or to SICP or HtDP than `#lang racket` is.