# Selecting student language in Racket source code

Tags: racket, htdp

I am trying to write a source file for DrRacket that specifies one of the languages from **How to Design Programs Teaching Languages** (see [the Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/htdp-langs.html)). I know I can select such a language in the DrRacket menu, but I would like to specify it using a `#lang` directive and have DrRacket recognize the language automatically.

I cannot find any documentation about the strings that I need to use instead of `racket` in the initial line

```
#lang racket
```

Where can I find the documentation on this? Or can these languages only be selected from DrRacket's menu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
#lang htdp/bsl
```

(or `htdp/bsl+`, `htdp/isl`, `htdp/isl+`, or `htdp/asl`) but it's ["not in a complete shape, yet"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152632/13).

Comment: Thanks, `#lang htdp/bsl` seems to work (+1), even though DrRacket displays the name of the language as "htdp/bsl" instead of "Beginning Student".

Comment: @Giorgio Well, that's part of what's meant by "not in a complete shape". ;-)

Comment: Ok, but otherwise it should work (I should be able to do my homework, I hope ;-) ).

Comment: Using this runs an animated Big Bang program noticeably faster than running the same program with Beginning Student selected through the menu.