# Accessing a list inside struct in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

I have a structure as:

```
(define-struct abc (item-list x y))
```

I want to access elements of item-list which is a list iteratively. How do I achieve this in racket?

I tried:

```
(abc-item-list a)
```

but doesn't work.

Note: I am using Intermediate Student Language for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
#lang htdp/isl ;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303242/selecting-student-language-in-racket-source-code

(define-struct abc (item-list x y))
(define test (make-abc (list 1 2) 4 5))
(abc-item-list test)
; ==> (list 1 2)
```

Comment: also works without the #lang but with the language just selected through the menu.