# Increment and Decrement operators in scheme programming language

Tags: scheme, operators, racket, increment, decrement

What are the `increment` and `decrement` operators in `scheme` programming language.
I am using "Dr.Racket" and it is not accepting `-1+` and `1+` as operators.
And, I have also tried `incf` and `decf`, but no use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not defined as such since Scheme and Racket try to avoid mutation; but you can easily define them yourself:

```
(define-syntax incf
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ x)   (begin (set! x (+ x 1)) x))
    ((_ x n) (begin (set! x (+ x n)) x))))

(define-syntax decf
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ x)   (incf x -1))
    ((_ x n) (incf x (- n)))))
```

then

```
> (define v 0)
> (incf v)
1
> v
1
> (decf v 2)
-1
> v
-1
```

Note that these are syntactic extensions (a.k.a. macros) rather than plain procedures because Scheme does not pass parameters by reference.

Answer (score 11):

Your reference to “DrRacket” somewhat suggests you’re in Racket. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152416/differences-between-lang-scheme-and-lang-racket), you may already be effectively using `#lang racket`. Either way, you’re probably looking for [`add1`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._add1%29%29) and `sub1`.

```
-> (add1 3)
4
-> (sub1 3)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

The operators 1+ and -1+ do /not/ mutate, as a simple experiment in MIT Scheme will show:

```
1 ]=> (define a 3)
;Value: a
1 ]=> (1+ a)
;Value: 4
1 ]=> (-1+ a)
;Value: 2
1 ]=> a
;Value: 3
```

So you can implement your own function or syntactic extensions of those functions by having them evaluate to (+ arg 1) and (- arg 1) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to just define simple functions like these yourself.

```
;; Use: (increment x)
;; Before: x is a number
;; Value: x+1
(define (increment x)
  (+ 1 x) 
)
```

Comment: This will not change that value of variable you are passing. Have a look here: http://ideone.com/KEgO9g