# How can I create a Racket #lang?

Tags: racket

I want to create a simple package, with only `my-lang/main.rkt` that I can use as the first line of a racket file:

```
#lang my-lang
;... my-lang code ...
```

To clarify quickly, notice that this is **not** the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152416/differences-between-lang-scheme-and-lang-racket), because I do not want the lang line to be `#lang s-exp my-lang`.  My current code already works this way, as it exports a `#%module-begin`.

I just want to use my expander to parse the input file/REPL session.  Please give a complete runnable example; everywhere I've found only gives either half examples, or ones that require `reader` or `s-exp`.

Comment: There's an example in the Guide: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-languages.html

Comment: I saw that, but could not find a way to use it to answer my question.  If you can use this guide to write the example I'm looking for, then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Specifically https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/language-collection.html

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work on the command line `racket -I my-lang` results in `#%top-interaction: unbound identifier` instead of printing out the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom reader.

To do that, you need a `/lang/reader.rkt`
or make a `reader` submodule of `main`.

The relevant chapter in the docs:
https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/language-collection.html

Here is an example of the first approach:

https://github.com/soegaard/minipascal/blob/master/minipascal/lang/reader.rkt