# How to declare a variable inside a procedure in Scheme: define: not allowed in an expression context

Tags: list, scheme

I'm a C# programmer learning Scheme, and I have a lot of troubles, because I don't understand Scheme.

I have write it this code with a lot of help:

```
#lang racket

(define sort-asc-by-second
  (lambda (lst)
    (sort lst
          (lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y))))))

(define sum
  (lambda (lst)
    (apply + (map cdr lst))
  )
)

(define my-function
  (lambda (lst)
   (
    (define sorted (sort-asc-by-second lst))
    (define suma (sum lst))
    (define lista (map (lambda (p) (cons (car p) (/ (cdr p) suma)))))
   ))
)
```

But I get the following error:

> define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define sorted
>   (sort-asc-by-second lst))

At this line:

```
(define sorted (sort-asc-by-second lst))
```

How can I declare a variable? Maybe, the problem here is that I'm a C# programmer and I don't understand Scheme.

Comment: local might be what you want. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do though.

Comment: Programming in Scheme in very different from something like C#. If you try to program in Scheme like you would in C# you're in for a world of pain.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thanks, but your comments don't help so much. You could add books or tutorials instead of saying the obvious.

Comment: Just a note, it looks like you're learning Racket, not Scheme, based on the first line of your code. The two are very similar though, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345397/how-is-racket-different-from-scheme. Are you specifically trying to learn Scheme for something, or just any LISP dialect?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I have to learn Scheme, but my professor said that we have to use DrRacket. But there isn't any `#lang Scheme` in DrRacket. Maybe there is another interpreter for Scheme that I can use.

Comment: If you are using DrRacket then there's a good chance you are learning Racket, since DrRacket is a Racket IDE. The professor might be referring to it as Scheme since the old name for Racket is `PLT Scheme`, and the two languages are very similar, especially at a beginner level. But I can't say for certain without seeing your course material.  Also, does the textbook for your course not cover enough?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso He said that we can learn Scheme with the book: Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum Days. I have asked about if we are going to use Scheme or Racket, and he said Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what this program is trying to do, but the current error you are seeing is due to an extra pair of brackets.

```
(define my-function
  (lambda (lst)

    (define sorted (sort-asc-by-second lst))
    (define suma (sum lst))
    (define lista (map (lambda (p) (cons (car p) (/ (cdr p) suma)))))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's going to be very important for you to follow the steps of the [Design Recipe](https://htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/). In this case:

- write a signature: the types that the function takes in and returns.
- Write test cases, using check-equal?.
- Follow the template for the data that you've chosen.

Put differently (and perhaps a bit more bluntly): stop wandering. Start designing!

Comment: Yes, absolutely.